# Vaadin wrong route after login

Tags: spring-security, routes, vaadin

I implemented a login with this
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tutorial/login-and-authentication
docs.
I also added a view with RouteAlias("") but after login I got redirected to

/sw-runtime-resources-precache.js

This looks really weird. I tried to find a place to manually set the redirect to a path or route but I did not find a solutions yet. Does anybody know why I did not get redirected to the home path?

This is my Security Config

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

```
@Resource
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/login";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    // Vaadin handles CSRF internally
    http.csrf().disable()

        // Register our CustomRequestCache, which saves unauthorized access attempts, so the user is redirected after login.
        .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())

        // Restrict access to our application.
        .and().authorizeRequests()

        // Allow all Vaadin internal requests.
        .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()

        // Allow all requests by logged-in users.
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        // Configure the login page.
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
        .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)

        // Configure logout
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider()
{
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}


/*@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()
{
    UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
        .password("{noop}userpass")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}*/

/**
 * Allows access to static resources, bypassing Spring Security.
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
{
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
        // Client-side JS
        "/VAADIN/**",

        // the standard favicon URI
        "/favicon.ico",

        // the robots exclusion standard
        "/robots.txt",

        // web application manifest
        "/manifest.webmanifest",
        "/sw.js",
        "/offline.html",

        // icons and images
        "/icons/**",
        "/images/**",
        "/styles/**",

        // (development mode) H2 debugging console
        "/h2-console/**");
}
```

}

Comment: This should normally work. Can you please show your security configuration class?

Comment: I changed it and posted also the config

Comment: You must use VaadinWebSecurity to make annotation based security work. Go to https://start.vaadin.com and create a new project with security enabled and checkout the configuratoin